# oracle trigger select updated row

Tags: oracle, triggers

I'm trying to build a trigger which takes the specific updated row and insert it into another table, but I'm not able to build it.

This is what I was able to build:

```
CREATE OD REPLACE TRIGGER Z_ONUPDATELOGIN
AFTER UPDATE OF LAST_LOGGED_IN_DATE ON CMN_SEC_USERS csu
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Z_LOGIN (name, login_date) 
    select first_name||last_name, 
           last_logged_in_date 
      from cmn_sec_users usr 
     where usr.id=csu.id;
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you deal with triggers you can use the :NEW and :OLD keyword to work with the new and old values of the row you are modifying. In your case try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Z_ONUPDATELOGIN
  AFTER UPDATE OF LAST_LOGGED_IN_DATE ON CMN_SEC_USERS
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Z_LOGIN (name, login_date) 
    VALUES (:NEW.first_name || :NEW.last_name, 
            :NEW.last_logged_in_date);  
END;
```

Comment: -1, because this doesn't work. You can only use :NEW and :OLD in row-level-triggers ("FOR EACH ROW"). And I see two additional syntax errors.

Comment: Still not good, although I see your answer got accepted because he/she received just enough clues. If you'd create a dummy table and the trigger yourself, you'd see the syntax errors. And it allows you to post tested answers.

Comment: it seems that Colin edited it. I didn't try the code because I had no time to create table and trigger, but it seems that it was enough. In my opinion if they don't create a demo in SQLFiddle or at least the code to generate their tables/data, they can't expect always a complete answer